# kendo grid cell appear with animation in each cell and each rows like solitaire cards

Tags: jquery, angularjs, animation, kendo-grid, effects

i try to add animation on kendo grid on appearing cells and rows but cant.

i want to add animation of each row's cells to appear after last one.

search and googling has many results for detailRow that i dont want. more articles with dataBound that speak about after cells and datas shows up.

i want to add effect on all cells to appear one after one.

this is angularjs rtl standard project

```
<div  id="grid" class="k-rtl" kendo-grid="grid" k-options="mainGridOptions" k-rebind="mainGridOptions">
```

like this [Console.log](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/slider/events) in this page that its sources [here](https://javascriptexamples.info/snippet/javascript/consolejs_dphoebus_javascript)

but we want to appear kendo grid like:

```
   MATRIX:[0,0] then [0,1] then .... then [0,N]

   [1,0] then [1,1] then .... then [1,N]

   ...

   [M,0] then [M,1] then .... then [M,N]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can provide a solution jQuery based as basically the approach should be the same for your angular application:

- Start with an hidden grid
- Display the grid-header on Databound event
- Display each cell of each row on Databound event as well within a setTimeout function to provide an animation effect.

Please, checkout the snippet below as an example.
[Note: use visibility: hidden css attribute because display: none on the parent won't let you display childs]

```
<div id="grid" style="visibility: hidden"></div>

<script>
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    selectable: "multiple cell",
    allowCopy: true,
    columns: [
        { field: "productName" },
        { field: "category" }
    ],
    dataBound: gridDataBound,  
    dataSource: [
        { productName: "Tea", category: "Beverages" },
        { productName: "Coffee", category: "Beverages" },
        { productName: "Ham", category: "Food" },
        { productName: "Bread", category: "Food" }
    ]
});

function gridDataBound(e){
  $(".k-grid-header").css("visibility", "visible");

  var rows = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").items();
  var columnNumber = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").columns.length;
  var animationSpeed = 500;

  $.each(rows, function(index, row){    
    setTimeout(function(){        
      $.each($(row).find("td"), 

             function(i, cell){                 
                        var interval = animationSpeed / columnNumber * i;
                        setTimeout(function(){
                        $(cell).css("visibility", "visible");
                        }, interval);
             });

     }, animationSpeed * index)
  });
}
</script>
```

Comment: thats great. is this possible to fly border when appear the cells ? from cell[0,0] to target location then appear?? two animation together?

Comment: is this codepen is correct? https://codepen.io/sabertaba/pen/QveeRr or this jsfiddle page : https://jsfiddle.net/saber13812002/902yz5fg/1/

Comment: Probably some reference is missing 'cause i get *kendo is not defined*. Why don't you test it on kendo dojo?